# Integral value in csv file verification using pandas module

Tags: pandas

I am new to python pandas module and trying to use it to for simple purpose of validating the positive integral values of "Height" field in csv file.

## test.csv

```
Name,Height
Name1,1234
Name2,1234.2
Name3,-1234
Name4,
```

Is there a way to identify all the invalid values ( negative, float,string, blank ) using pandas functions. I tried  multiple options, which are specific to one invalid values but creates exception for other type of invalid values:

- Catches empty values or non numeric values but not the floating and negative values:
  `df['Height'].convert_objects(False,True,False,False).isnull()`
- Catches floating values but raises exception for empty and non-numeric values 
  `df['Height'] != df['Height'].astype(numpy.int64)`
- Forcing type during read_csv throws exception for non numeric values `pandas.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'Height':int}`

Any suggestion to capture all invalid combinations in a better way or any other module for csv file content validations. I tried csv, petl too where the header field type specification seems better controlled but not as feature rich as pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the results, but here are a couple options, assuming you've already loaded into a dataframe using `df = pd.read_csv(myfile)`.

```
df['valid'] = np.where((df.Height >= 0) & (df.Height.replace('', 0.5).mod(1) == 0), True, False)
```

This adds a `valid` column as so:

```
    Name  Height  valid
0  Name1    1234   True
1  Name2  1234.2  False
2  Name3   -1234  False
3  Name4          False
```

Alternatively you could just filter out the invalid rows:

```
df = df[(df.Height >= 0) & (df.Height.replace('', 0.5).mod(1) == 0)]
```

Which leaves you with:

```
    Name Height
0  Name1   1234
```

Either way I've used the same `df.Height >= 0` to mark strings and negatives, and `df.Height.replace('', 0.5).mod(1) == 0` to mark floats for removal. I did the `replace('', 0.5)` to get around `mod` not liking strings - there may be a more graceful way.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

> Catches empty values or non numeric values but not the floating and
>   negative values:
>   `df['Height'].convert_objects(False,True,False,False).isnull()`

But by converting the series to numeric you do not have to deal with non-numeric values anymore, which is good.

Btw `convert_objects`is now deprecated and `to_numeric` is recommended instead.

> Catches floating values but raises exception for empty and non-numeric
>   values
>   `df['Height'] != df['Height'].astype(numpy.int64)`

Non-numeric values won't be an issue if you do this with the numeric-only series above (they have become nan's). To avoid exceptions on nan's use `Series.round()` instead of `Series.astype(numpy.int64)`

> Forcing type during read_csv throws exception for non numeric values
>   `pandas.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'Height':int}`

At this point you do not need this.

So let's put it all toguether:

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # use io.StringIO with python3
import pandas as pd


def is_invalid(s):
    x = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
    return (x.isnull()) | (x < 0) | (x != x.round())


text = '''Name,Height
Name1,1234
Name2,1234.2
Name3,-1234
Name4,
Name5,some string'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))
print(df.assign(invalid=is_invalid(df['Height'])))

    Name      Height  invalid
0  Name1         1234   False
1  Name2       1234.2    True
2  Name3        -1234    True
3  Name4          NaN    True
4  Name5  some string    True
```